# Google API Python Client: MediaIoBaseDownload: Problems with 'contentEncoding' of type 'gzip'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I am running in circles trying to figure out how to download a CSV file that is 'contentEncoded' as 'gzip' from Google cloud using their **[google-api-python-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client)**.

My issue, I am not able to download a file that has 'contentEncoding' as 'gzip', nor its 'md5Hash' matching what was downloaded, nor its 'size' matching what was downloaded (much larger).

This is the object's metadata:

```
{  
   'selfLink':'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_0123456789/o/stats%2Finstalls%2Finstalls_com.foobar.helloworld_201512_country.csv',
   'etag':'ETAG=',
   'mediaLink':'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_0123456789/o/stats%2Finstalls%2Finstalls_com.foobar.helloworld_201512_country.csv?generation=1451747575795000&alt=media',
   'id':'pubsite_prod_rev_0123456789/stats/installs/installs_com.foobar.helloworld_201512_country.csv/1451747575795000',
   'name':'stats/installs/installs_com.foobar.helloworld_201512_country.csv',
   'contentType':'text/csv; charset=utf-16le',
   'contentEncoding':'gzip',
   'size':9260,
   'md5Hash':'MD5HASH==',
   'kind':'storage#object',
   'crc32c':'CRC32C==',
   'storageClass':'STANDARD'
}
```

When I download object's media, and it has 2 problems:

1. metadata md5Hash value does not match download's calculated using md5(data).hexdigest().
2. metadata size (9260) does not match download size (288386).

Here is the code:

```
request = service.objects().get_media(
    bucket=bucket_name,
    object=object_name
)

with io.BytesIO() as compressed_file:    
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(compressed_file, request, chunksize=1024*1024)

    progressless_iters = 0
    done = False
    while not done:
        error = None
        try:
            progress, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            if progress:
                self.logger.info(
                    'Download %d%%.' % int(progress.progress() * 100)
                )
        except HttpError as err:
            error = err
            if err.resp.status < 500:
                raise
        except RETRYABLE_ERRORS as err:CSV file that is 'contentEncoded' as 'gzip'
              error = err

    if error:
        progressless_iters += 1
        self._HandleProgresslessIter(error, progressless_iters)
    else:
        progressless_iters = 0

    self.logger.info('\nDownload complete!')

    data = compressed_file.getvalue()

    original_md5 = src_obj_metadata['md5Hash']

    md5_returned = md5(data).hexdigest()

    # Finally compare original MD5 with freshly calculated
    if original_md5 == md5_returned:
        logger.info("MD5 verified.")
    else:
        logger.info("MD5 verification failed!.")

    with open(download_file_name, 'wb') as fh_compressed:
        fh_compressed.write(data)
```

If I try to check the 'md5Hash' after downloaded file is closed, it errors:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Here is that code:

```
# Open,close, read file and calculate MD5 on its contents 
with open(download_file_name) as file_to_check:
    # read contents of the file
    data = file_to_check.read()    
    # pipe contents of the file through
    md5_returned = md5(data).hexdigest()
```

If I try to decompress the downloaded file, it errors:

```
OSError: Not a gzipped file
```

Here is the code:

```
with open(download_file_name, 'rb') as fh_compressed:
    with open(csv_file_name, 'wb') as fh_decompressed:
        fh_decompressed.write(gzip.decompress(fh_compressed.read()))
```

What am I doing wrong in order to properly download a CSV file that is 'contentEncoded' as 'gzip'?

Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I dropped the approach in using **google-api-python-client**, because I found no way required to set header with 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate' other than modifying said library.

Instead, I had found 2 solutions:

1. [Reading PlayStore csv review files from Google storage bucket using Java App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727871/reading-playstore-csv-review-files-from-google-storage-bucket-using-java-app-eng)
2. Using Google Cloud HTTP/REST API and set header with 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'.

I used the second solution.